# Is putting up bounties broken?

Tags: bug, status-norepro

I just tried to put up a bounty on the following question:

[Desktop Facebook application for Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/813084/522934)

The Dialog for selecting how hight the bounty shall be comes up but the <kbd>Next</kbd> Button doesnt seem to have a link target and it happens nothing.

I tried:

- hard reloading the page (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f5</kbd>) as well as normal reloading the page (<kbd>f5</kbd>), nothing changes.
- logging out of the whole network closing down all pages, cleaning the cache, disabling all add-ons to no avail either.
- was able to put a bounty on the question via mobile firefox.
- tried another question then afterwards in browser on PC, again nothing.

As there was a question about what is in the console, here it is:

```
soup injecting fixes  SOUP.user.js:1888:23
soup init complete  i-think-i-fork-bombed-my-server-with-a-cron-job-whats-happening-here-and-how:30:25
soup setup complete  i-think-i-fork-bombed-my-server-with-a-cron-job-whats-happening-here-and-how:30:25
TypeError: $(...).live is not a function[Learn More]  i-think-i-fork-bombed-my-server-with-a-cron-job-whats-happening-here-and-how:5:5
    AddKbdShortcuts https://askubuntu.com/questions/862889/i-think-i-fork-bombed-my-server-with-a-cron-job-whats-happening-here-and-how:5:5
    <anonymous> https://askubuntu.com/questions/862889/i-think-i-fork-bombed-my-server-with-a-cron-job-whats-happening-here-and-how:137:38
    n.Callbacks/i https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js:2:27444
    n.Callbacks/j.fireWith https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js:2:28213
    .ready https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js:2:30004
    K https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js:2:30366
soup JS fixes applied  i-think-i-fork-bombed-my-server-with-a-cron-job-whats-happening-here-and-how:30:25
soup subscribed to realtime feed for question 862889 on site 89  i-think-i-fork-bombed-my-server-with-a-cron-job-whats-happening-here-and-how:30:25
```

Is there currently a bug? Using firefox 50.1.0 - canonical 1.0.

Comment: I just tried it, and it works.

Comment: Weird :/ then the question arises have i been banned from putting bounties ? :D

Comment: Not that I can tell.  Try logging-out, and log back in, and try it.  Let me know what happens.

Comment: Will do that, really curious right now

Comment: Tested here (Ubuntu 16.04, Chrome 55.0.2883.75), works fine for me. Anything in the console?

Comment: Well i logged out closed all my firefox windows, cleared the cache etc. etc. and it doesnt seem to have a link target on the next button :-/

Comment: Well since it seems that I cant get it to work in browser on PC, I just did it on mobile browser. Still no chance, I even tried another question too.

Comment: Just tested it here, from multiple browsers (including IE11 from a Windows VM) without issue, not sure what's up but it seems to be working for everyone else everywhere.

Comment: You never answered if there was anything in the console. Probably is.

Comment: @Seth Yes a type error, but no clue what this means for me then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O.k. I found out what has caused this mess:

> https://gist.github.com/BrockA/2476594
>   A script to add `<kbd>` shortcut functionality to the site

A greasemonkey script which is terrible outdated it seems but still is to be found on https://stackapps.com/questions/3341/kbd-markup-shortcuts

Comment: Sorry about that (and the delay).  Revamped the script for the site changes and added some extra tag support.

Answer (score 1):

A picture is worth a thousand words... It works for me:

[image: Bounty]

Comment: The name is "Videonauth" and not "VideoAuth"... :P

Comment: My apologies... I see a handle and based on recent conversations my brain converts it English: "Video Authority" was in my head :)